# how I can list files from an ftp ? on a website done in self hostig nancy with C#

Tags: ftp, nancy

I have a website with self hostig nancy, and I want to display a list of files my ftp directory , Any idea how? . Thank you

Comment: You're looking for the `Directory` class.

Comment: I have my directory  ftp, I just want to show the files that are on the ftp server, in my  website that can be downloaded.